# How to edit a post meta data in a Gutenberg Block?

Tags: post-meta, block-editor

I am trying to follow the instruction in the [Gutenberg Handbook](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/attributes/#meta) to create a block that can change meta data of a post.

Though when I try to use the `setAttributes` function from `props` to save the new data it persisted on the page, but is not actually saved back to the database, as I believe the Handbook states it should if it's source is `meta`. I must be missing something, but I cannot find a resource to help.

php:

```
   $args = ...

   register_post_type('event', $args);

   register_meta('event', 'event_location', [
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single' => true,
        'type' => 'string'
    ]);
```

javascript:

```
registerBlockType('my-plugin/event-location', {
  title: 'Event Location',
  category: 'widgets',

  attributes: {
    location: {
      type: 'string',
      source: 'meta',
      meta: 'event_location'
    }
  },

  edit ({ className, attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const { location } = attributes

    function updateContent (e) {
      setAttributes({ location: e.target.value })
    }

    return el(
      'p',
      { className: className },
      el(
        'input',
        { value: location, onChange: updateContent }
      )
    )
  },

  save () {
    return null
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think I found the answer [here](https://iandunn.name/2017/03/30/exposing-custom-post-type-meta-for-only-a-single-api-endpoint/). The first argument to `register_meta` is not post type but `object_type`, which is in my case should be `post` rather than `taxonomy` or `comment`. The function description, found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_meta), states as of WordPress 4.9.2 the correct parameter is `post`. Once I switched it everything worked.

```
register_meta('post', 'event_location', [
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'single' => true,
    'type' => 'string'
]);
```

Also, [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/5622) is a Github issue related to the same problem.

Comment: It's not quite that `register_meta` doesn't work for custom post types, it's that `object_type` and `post_type` are not the the same thing. Post, Taxonomy and Comment are object types. Page and Post are different post types, but they're both the Post object type.

Comment: Thank you @JacobPeattie, I understand. I am new to WordPress and getting used to the nomenclature. I will adjust my answer.

Comment: Since 4.9.8 you can use [register_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_meta/) and include the post type, so in your case it would be: `register_post_meta('event', 'event_location', /*...*/ )`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can properly register the custom post meta to make it accessible on the REST API:

```
/**
 * Registers the custom_post_meta field.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function register_custom_post_meta_field() {
    register_post_meta(
        'post',
        'custom_post_meta',
        [
            'type'         => 'string',
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'single'       => true,
        ]
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_post_meta_field' );
```

The, using the approach below you can read and update the post meta value:

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useSelect, useDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
import { PanelBody, PanelRow, TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { InspectorControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

/**
 * My Custom Block
 */
const MyCustomBlock = () => {
    const META_KEY = 'custom_post_meta'; // This is your custom meta name
    const { editPost } = useDispatch('core/editor');
    const meta = useSelect((select) =>
        select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')
    );
    const { [META_KEY]: customMeta } = meta;

    const onCustomMetaChange = (newValue) => {
        editPost({
            meta: { ...meta, [META_KEY]: newValue },
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelBody title={__('Settings', 'textdomain')}>
                    <PanelRow>
                        <TextControl
                            label={__('Custom Meta', 'textdomain')}
                            value={customMeta}
                            onChange={onCustomMetaChange}
                        />
                    </PanelRow>
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>
        </div>
    );
};
```

For a complete guide, you can follow this tutorial on mine to [create, save and update the post meta in the Gutenberg block editor](https://jeffreycarandang.com/how-to-enable-read-and-update-post-meta-in-the-wordpress-block-editor-gutenberg/).