# Add To Gutenberg Sidebar

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to make sense of how to add custom page options to the right side of the Gutenberg interface. I don't *think* need a content block, I just need to be able to add a page-specific configuration, but can't seem to make it work correctly.

Pre-Gutenberg I would resolve this with a metabox placed in the right side, however, from what I'm reading it sounds like metaboxes are going to be a bad practice moving forward.

Comment: Maybe this could have a hint? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/303330/16301 Also, you should post here what you have tried so far in order to get specific help.

Comment: I think this article does a good job explaining a custom sidebar in the editor if that is indeed what you are looking for: https://awhitepixel.com/blog/add-a-custom-inspector-sidebar-in-wordpress-gutenberg-with-post-meta/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to work with the Gutenberg sidebar, WordPress has a provided tutorial that will teach you exactly how to do this:
https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/plugin-sidebar-0/

Comment: Any news on this subject?

Comment: I think you have to use a Gutenberg Plugin and register a custom sidebar. Check out this repo https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/plugins/README.md

Still working out more details, but I will publish here as I learn.

Comment: Ah HA! Getting closer: https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/plugin-sidebar-0/